# Angular services and coffee-script classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

What I would like is to define a static class as a service in angular.

Here is what I would like:

```
class MyService extends ServiceBase
   @thing  = 'thing'
   @method = -> alert 'I fired'


# neither of these work
angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', -> MyService
angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', MyService

# these work but prevent the use of `extends`
angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', ->
   @thing  = 'thing'
   @method = -> alert 'I fired'

angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', ->
   thing  : 'thing'
   method : -> alert 'I fired'

myService =
   thing  : 'thing'
   method : -> alert 'I fired'

angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', -> myService
```

The error I get when using classes is a type error. Angular wants an `Object` but all coffee classes are type `Function`. Is there a way around this?

Please note, this is because I want to use `.service` NOT `.factory`. I know how to fix this with `.factory` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note, this is because I want to use .service NOT .factory. I know how to fix this with .factory already.

Why? lol.

Okay, anyhow try this:

```
angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', -> 
    {
       $get: -> MyService
    }
```

or this:

```
angular.module('Foo').service 'MyService', -> $get: -> myService
```

#### Edit: responding to comments below...

> There is no constructor in my example.

There is, actually:

```
class MyService extends ServiceBase
```

`MyService` is a class constructor function that has a prototype of a new instance of `ServiceBase`. It's expecting to be called with the `new` keyword.

The functional equivalent in JavaScript is:

```
function MyService() {}

MyService.prototype = new ServiceBase();
```

So you see... constructor function.

So one of the problems you're likely going to run into is the fact you have to create a new instance of your MyService in every controller you pass it to, and each one of those instances is different. You'd be better off using an object literal to carry state, or at the very least creating a new instance of `MyService` and returning that directly from your service declaration. This is because **all angular services are, by default, singletons**, meaning it's always going to be the same instance.

Try the following to allow sharing values between two controllers.

```
angular.module('Foo').service 'storageService' -> $get: -> {}

angular.module('Foo').controller 'SomeCtrl', class SomeCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, storageService) ->
    $scope.storage = storageService
    $scope.storage.i = $scope.storage.i || 0
    $scope.increment = -> $scope.storage.i++

angular.module('Foo').controller 'OtherCtrl', class OtherCtrl
   constructor: ($scope, storageService) ->
     $scope.storage = storageService;     
     $scope.storage.i = $scope.storage.i || 0
     $scope.decrement = -> $scope.storage.i--;
```

Anyhow, I hope that helps. Happy holidays.

Comment: `.service` and `.factory` have different behavior.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But if you're returning a class, what do you have going on that you need to use `factory` instead of service? I'm only curious. It might help me improve my example.

Comment: I am using the service to share state between controllers.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the need for `service` over `factory` though. In theory you could create a shared data store like: `angular.module('Foo').factory 'sharedStore', -> {}`, and just use it like a dictionary everywhere.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying your wrong, I'm just trying to better answer the question. Since it seems unacceptable to you. Perhaps theres more to the question?

Comment: returning a ctor function isn't going to help you share state, either, unless you're implementing your own singleton, which isn't necessary for services in Angular.

Comment: There is no constructor in my example.

Comment: Added responses to the answer. Take it or leave it. Best of luck and happy holidays.

Comment: Interesting how the focus shifted to controller syntax

Comment: Oh, I was just showing how to use the service in the controllers. I'm not sure what you're doing for controller syntax. Since controller definitions are constructor functions, in CS I'd use a class.  I honestly don't prefer CS for Angular work though, partially because the constructor function syntax is a little more verbose.

Comment: So in practice when I call my service with `$get` what I get is an object like this `$get : ->` instead of what `$get` returns.

Comment: Well, you'd never really call the *service* with $get. That's on the *provider*. But when you inject your service, it will call the $get method and inject whatever it returns... *but* it will only call $get once, after that, you'll get the same instance back every time.

Comment: I'm saying with the syntax your provided, it did not call $get. But rather provided the object containing $get.

Comment: right... with `module.service()` you return an object that has a `$get` function on it. with `module.factory()` you just return whatever the `$get` function would return.

Comment: So you are saying that every time I consume this service I need to run `$get` myself? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Not at all. Angular calls `$get` internally to get an instance of the service.